# Como autenticar login com SELECT em uma tabela? Sistema de login Pyside2 sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite3, pyside

Eu estou criando um sistema de login simples, onde o usuário coloca os dados inseridos em uma tabela. Mas no código ao comparar os dados, ou ele ENTRA mesmo com os espaços em branco ou informações erradas ou ele acusa como incorreta qualquer tipo de tentativa, mesmo corretas.

Segue a função de criar a tabela:

```
    def createTableusers(self):
    c = self.conn.cursor()
    c.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS usuarios(
    user varchar(20))''')
    self.conn.commit()
    c.close()
```

Segue a classe e função de inserir:

```
class Users(object):

def __init__(self, nome = '', senha = '', operador = '', entrada = '', saida = '', creditos = '',):
    self.info = {}
    self.nome = nome
    self.senha = senha
    self.operador = operador
    self.entrada = entrada
    self.saida = saida
    self.creditos = creditos

def insertOperador(self, operador, senha):
    try:


        bank = Bank()


        c = bank.conn.cursor()

        c.execute('''Insert into operadores(operador, senha)
                  values (?, ?)
                  ''', (operador, senha))

        bank.conn.commit()
        c.close()

        return "Operador cadastrado com sucesso!"

    except:
        return 'Erro na cadastro do operador'
```

Segue a função de SELECT:

```
    def selectOperador(self,operador,senha):
    bank = Bank()
    try:

        c = bank.conn.cursor()

        c.execute('''SELECT * FROM operadores
        WHERE operador = ? AND senha = ?
        ''', (operador, senha))

        ver = c.fetchall()
        if (operador in ver and senha in ver):
            return 'Operador conectado'

    except:
        return 'Ocorreu um erro na busca!'
```

Função de login:

```
    def login(self):
    u = Users()
    operador = txt_usuario.text()
    senha = txt_senha.text()
    entrar = u.selectOperador(operador,senha)

    if entrar == 'Operador conectado':
        print('VDC')
    else:
        msg = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Erro', 'Operador ou senha incorreta', QMessageBox.Ok)

        if msg == QMessageBox.Ok:
            pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando se usa o método fetchall() recebemos uma lista de resultados. Basta verificar se está vazia ou não.

```
if len(ver) > 0:
    return 'Operador conectado'
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso que tava faltando, você é nota 10, não, nota 11!